# Custom post type editor uses old tinyMCE

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor, tinymce

It is an old site made before the new block editor arrives. Now it's running WP 5.0.11, and I do not want to make an upgrade right now for various reasons.

The default post types are using the new block editor, but the custom post type still use the old TinyMCE and I even cannot insert images to it. The image problem wold not be a problem if I could switch to the block editor witch works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does the classic editor plugin not work for you? Your root problem is the out of date WordPress version, you need to resolve your other issues and update

Comment: As I mentioned the block editor is working in default post type, but in custom post type not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code where you defined your custom post type (in a custom plugin or in your `functions.php`file), you need to add this snippet for Gutenberg block editor support:

```
'show_in_rest' => true,
   'supports' => array('editor')
```

Here is an example:

```
function portfolio_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' )
            ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'supports' => array('editor')
        )
    );
}
 
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_post_type' );
```